# How to set adapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-adapter

I've got a `Fragment` whose `onCreateView()` callback returns a custom `View`. The View contains a GridView that I'd like to set an adapter on. Before I switched to using Fragments, I would simply find the `GridView` by Id and then set the `adapter`. For reasons I don't currently understand, the `GridView` is null when I try finding it by Id in my `FragmentsActivity`.

So, I'd like to set the adapter in the `fragment` itself. I'm assuming I need to do this in `onActivityCreated`, but I don't know how I'll set the `adapter` on the `GridView` that's contained within the View being returned by onCreateView. In other words, how do I grab hold of that View that's returned by `onCreateView` to set the `Adapter` on it?

EDIT - I just realized, I could probably just find the `GridView` in `onActivityCreated` and set the `adapter` there, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For reasons I don't currently understand, the GridView is null when I try finding it by Id in my FragmentsActivity.

You created the `GridView` in the fragment in `onCreateView()`. Just hold onto it in a data member of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes a little late (and also I am quite new to Android). But what about using `getView()` inside of `onActivityCreated`, instead of finding it by ID?